# Converging $f(x) = x$ to a constant value

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

I'm looking for a cutoff function $f_c(x)$ that I can use like so:

$$ f(x) = xf_c(x)$$

and the result will be the same as $f(x)=x$ except it converges to a constant value at a desired cutoff $x_c$. My first attempt is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUfTn.jpg), where $f(x)$ converges to $c$ and $c=1$ in this case.

I achieved this using the smoothing function

$$ s(x) = 0.5 + 0.5tanh[b(x-a)] $$

along with

$$ f(x) = [1-s(x)]x + s(x)(c) $$

where $c$ is a constant value I'd like to converge to and $a=c$.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUfTn.jpg) is the correct shape that I want, except I need the following:

1) The cutoff function to be of the form $f_c(x) = f(x)/x$ so I can write the final function as $f(x) = xf_c(x)$.

2) The function $f(x)=xf_c(x)$ must not ever be greater than $c$ and must go more smoothly to $c$. This was not accomplished in the above example.

3) $f(x)=xf_c(x)$ and $g(x)=-xf_c(x)$ must be symmetric about the x axis.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your point $(1)$ seems awkward: if $f_c(x)=x/f(x)$, then $f(x)=x/f_c(x)$ (rather than $f(x)=xf_c(x)$).

Comment: You're right, sorry. I fixed that. I meant $f_c(x) = f(x)/x$.